# Swift println doesn't print array value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm brand new learning Swift and I was wondering what I am doing wrong here? I like to play around with code to gain an understanding.

```
var shoppingList = ["pound of catfish", "bottle of fresh water", "bag of tulips", "can of blue paint"]

println("Susie checks her Shopping List to find that a \(shoppingList[2]) is her third item.")
```

I'm trying to figure out why the output doesn't say "Susie checks her Shopping List to find that a bag of tulips is her third item." as opposed to what it says currently: exactly as above, "Susie checks her Shopping List to find that a (shoppingList[2]) is her third item."

I know this is an ultra basic concept and all but I want to make sure I understand everything 100%.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are simply outputting the string "(shoppingList[2])".

To replace this with the value you want, you must first escape the string using a `\`.

```
var shoppingList = ["pound of catfish", "bottle of fresh water", "bag of tulips", "can of blue paint"]

"Susie checks her Shopping List to find that a \(shoppingList[2]) is her third item."
```

This is called String Interpolation and you can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_381).

Answer (score 0):

You need a `\` in front of the `()`.

```
var shoppingList = ["pound of catfish", "bottle of fresh water", "bag of tulips", "can of blue paint"]

"Susie checks her Shopping List to find that a \(shoppingList[2]) is her third item."
```

[String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_381)

Answer (score 0):

As in Apple docs:

> “Swift uses string interpolation to include the name of a constant or
>   variable as a placeholder in a longer string, and to prompt Swift to
>   replace it with the current value of that constant or variable. Wrap
>   the name in parentheses and escape it with a backslash before the
>   opening parenthesis.”

In your case, the code should be:

```
println("Susie checks her Shopping List to find that a \(shoppingList[2]) is her third item.")
```